# Always stumble on this error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: jquery, reactjs

im currently working on a personal project of mine and always stumble on this error.

> // Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import CategoryListItem from './CategoryListItem'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { ApplicationContext } from './../contexts/ApplicationContext'


export default function CategoryList(){

    let { products} = useContext(ApplicationContext)

    let categoryDisplay = products.map( product =>{
        return(
            <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} key={product._id}>
                <CategoryListItem product={product}/>
            </Col>
        )
    })


    return(
        <Container className="my-5">
            <Row>
                {categoryDisplay}
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: can you console products .see what you get .look like its null

Comment: Why so many tags? `property` is referring to a attribute of an object. `map` is a specific property that's usually available on arrays. Clearly `products` isn't an array but is actually undefined. What do you think the error means?

Comment: Please, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please, prevent tag spamming. This is considered as rude. (I don't see how tag [tag:c++] is related to your question.)

Comment: sorry about the tags, its just that the system is not allowing me to post this without putting at least 5 different tags, and thankyou for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that products is an array.

```
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap' 
import CategoryListItem from './CategoryListItem' 
import { useContext } from 'react' 
import { ApplicationContext } from './../contexts/ApplicationContext'


export default function CategoryList(){

let { products} = useContext(ApplicationContext)

let categoryDisplay = products? products.map( product =>{
    return(
        <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} key={product._id}>
            <CategoryListItem product={product}/>
        </Col>
    )
}):" "


return(
    <Container className="my-5">
        <Row>
            {categoryDisplay}
        </Row>
    </Container>
)
}
```

Also do a check before mapping, in case if it null